# Too few arguments laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do my own method of registration (in my project only admins can registrate). So i did UserController and registration function:

```
public function registration(array $data)
    {
        
          if ($data['submit']) {
                  $user=new User;
                  $user->name=$data['name'];
                  $user->surname=$data['surname'];
                  $user->email=$data['email'];
                  $user->password=Hash::make($data['password']);
                  $user->save();
                  
    }

        return view('registration');
    }
```

but i'm getting error:

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\UserController::registration(), 0 passed in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\projecticable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php
> on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

And it alludes to `public function registration(array $data)`

There is no problems with view and route(it shows without registration function).

Comment: Use public function registration($data = array()) instead of public function registration(array $data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function input is incorrect, you should change it to:

```
public function registration($data = array())
```

Comment: yeah, it works, thank you very much! But why in RegisterController it looks like 
`protected function validator(array $data)` ?

Comment: @ichwillkin it is ok too but you should do: array $data = array()